# Wordpress The7 File System not Accessible

Tags: wordpress-theming

I use Wordpress and the Theme "The7"
When i try to update some information the plug-in said that he cannot "Cannot access file system."
Same in : The 7 > Service Information
...
FS Accessible: No.
...

Does any file(s)/folder(s) need an extra permission ?

Answer (score 1):

Update wp-config.php and add

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```